# Java : Is `@WebParam` optional?

Tags: java, jax-ws

I put in place a simple web service using JAX-WS RI (default Java implementation).

I read many tutorials where I find web methods with parameters declared with the `WebParam` annotation. Ex:

```
@WebMethod
void foobar(@WebParam("foo") String bar);
```

In my case I didn't put it and it worked.

Is `@WebParam` optional ?

Regards.

Comment: Have you tried to remove it?

Comment: If I put `WebParam` or if I remove it, It doesn't have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its Optional, This Option is basically used to give a custom name to your web-Method param, and also the proper format is:

```
@WebMethod
void foobar(@WebParam(name="foo") String bar);
```

Also there's a concept of Holder's as well so this annonation can be help ful in that as well, i.e. if you want your method to return more one thing then try the method below

```
@WebMethod
void foobar(@WebParam(name="foo", Mode=INOUT) Holder<String>bar,
@WebParam(name="param2", Mode=INOUT) Holder<String> newParam);
```

Now what this will do , you can input two string in the web service and get in return two ouputs from that service's method

Last thing to mention there are three Mode's supported

```
IN
OUT
INOUT
```